# Making lite and pro versions in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I using Xcode 6.1.1 on OSX 10.10.2

What should be the approach in XCode to manage two different type of apps build on same source code?
 I am planning to release a lite version of my current **Mac** app.
In lite app only the `icon file` and a `int` will change. Rest of the code remains the same.

Comment: What was the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two targets in the project, as they share same code files but properties like icon etc will be different, also add some identifier to recognise the target.
As show in screenshot, two targets are there and C flag has been set to identify the build version whether it is lite or pro.
[Adding Target Link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-tutorial-for-ios-xcode-4-quick-start-guide/ghunitsetup_006)
[image]

Here is image link:
[above img link](http://i58.tinypic.com/15xptmc.png)